# MvvmCross: How to use the "PassEventArgsToCommand" on "MvxEventToCommand"

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, command, mvvmcross

Maybe a simple question here, I tried to set PassEventArgsToCommand=True on MvxEventToCommand. But found no benefit.

The event/command gets fired on my ViewModel for "True" and for "False".This is OK, no complains here. But how do I access the EventArgs on the ViewModel?

Also using MvxWithArgsEventToCommand (which sets PassEventArgsToCommand to true) had no effect. I looked online and in NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross samples but found no hints. I'm using WPF. Any help is much appreciated.

XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
    <commands:MvxEventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MyMandatory_SelectionChangedCommand, 
        Source={x:Reference MyView}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type syncfusion:ComboBoxAdv}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
        PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
    />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

ViewModel:

```
public IMvxCommand MyMandatory_SelectionChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand<Object>(e => MyMandatory_Changed(e));
    }
}

public void MyMandatory_Changed(Object e)
{
    if (e != null && e is ComboBoxAdv)
    {
        ComboBoxAdv cbo = (ComboBoxAdv)e;
        …Further code
    }
}
```

Comment: Some fairly old sample that worked with it are https://github.com/gshackles/NycCodeCamp8/blob/32c3632fa49191526a378f641236ec2c04ef10fd/Apps/CodeCamp.App.WindowsPhone/Views/PivotView.xaml#L50 and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/6f76d41c8f5b3555f3ed5d76f0c0fd8d2c929a79/Sample%20-%20CustomerManagement/CustomerManagement%20-%20AutoViews/CustomerManagement.WindowsPhone/Views/CustomerListView.xaml#L49... maybe try a simpler CommandParameter first - e.g. just use `True` for the CommandParameter - does that get through to `MyMandatory_Changed`?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Perhaps the question is too simple. Everything works so far. 
- The event calls my command. => OK
- I have an object there in "e". => OK
- The object is the full ComboBox instance which raises the event => OK
- Even the selected items are correct. => OK

But:
What is this property "PassEventArgsToCommand" for? Why exists a class MvxWithArgsEventToCommand? Some more data? Where?

Comment: OK, I found it. If one does not defines/binds "CommandParamter" in XAML then PassEventArgsToCommand and MvxWithArgsEventToCommand is useful. With PassEventArgsToCommand = true then in my "e" a SelectionChanged instance will be sent to my command with PassEventArgsToCommand = false only "null" arrives.
Case closed...

Comment: The mvx property exists so that the mvx event to command class looks and feels like the old EventToCommand helper from the Blend System.Windows.Interactivity class. If you want the history of where Blend's design came from... then you'd need to tag and phrase your question more openly (and attract some Avalon historians!)

Comment: Ha Ha! :-)
Admiteddly I missed the whole XAML UI Design boat a while ago when every CEO got exited if someone said "XML". I thought some negative things back then. But now there is heavy rowing on my side to catch up with you guys sitting in the luxury yachts since the CEO's are still exited about the same thing.
Maybe for little guys like me, some (any?) comments in the source code of the classes would help. It must not necessarily be history.

Comment: No - any comments I added 4 years ago would have become complete lies by now...